# Running ArcGIS field calculation using Python with algebraic expression using other field values as variables?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, multi-values

I'm trying to run a field calculation using multiple fields in a table as well as independent numeric values with python code in the field calculator window.  I've included the first 7 lines of the code below.  I'm not getting any syntax errors, but I'm also not getting any results.  The other fields used as variables include: `Appraised_Value`, `Ag_value`, and `TaxRate_Municipal`  Not sure how to fix it.

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```py
def Reclass( Exemp_Code_Int ) :
 if (Exemp_Code_Int == '0') :
  return (Appraised_Value / 100) * TaxRate_Municipal
 elif (Exemp_Code_Int == '2') :
  return (Ag_Value / 100) * TaxRate_Municipal
 elif (Exemp_Code_Int == '4') :
  return 0
```

Codeblock looks like this:

```py
 Reclass( !Exemp_Code_Int! )
```

Screenshot too:
      [image]

Comment: You need to pass those other fields into the function as arguments. In field calculator you do that by typing `!field_name!`. In your current method, they are not in scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All fields have to be included in the Reclass definition to be used by the calculation.

Reclass(!Exemp_Code_Int!, !Appraised_Value!, !TaxRate_Municipal!, !Ag_Value!, etc.)

Then those variables have to be included in the def of Reclass.

def Reclass(Exemp_Code_Int, Appraised_Value, TaxRate_Municipal, Ag_Value, etc.)

Also, if Exem_Code_Int is actually an integer value, then the logical comparison value cannot be a string.  I.e.,

if (Exemp_Code_Int == '0'):

must become:

if (Exemp_Code_Int == 0):

Comment: +1 about integer/string checking. Similarly @FelixTX83, unless you want floor division (i.e, `5/2` in python returns 2), you need one of your values to be a float. The easiest way is probably to change your code to `x/100.0`

Comment: Eureka!  Thank you so much Richard Fairhurst!  You hit three nails right on the head.  I've tried with a small sample and I'll apply it to the rest of the script later today.  Thanks again and well done!

Comment: This is the first question I've ever posted on here, so is there some way to mark this question as answered?

Comment: @FelixTX83 from the [Tour] you will learn that the Accept button serves that purpose